# League of legends resolution problem

Tags: 14.04, ati, wine, games, playonlinux

I've got 1 GB Radeon R9 270X and *League of legends*  was working fine. Recently I used a different monitor and the game seemed to adjust automatically .

I went back to my old monitor and I run the game and to my surprise the game opens in full screen mode but in a too big resolution. I can still see the desktop and the worst is I can see that on about a third of my screen the rest is black.

Please help. I've got a lan coming up!!

Comment: I would just remove the whole game and install it again, since it doesn't need any local content to work. Might be the quickest solution...

Answer (score 0):

I used to play normally for a couple of months, then suddenly I had the problem you described.
Not a monitor issue in my opinion. I used to change res ingame every time via options->video-> resolution raising it to 1980.

Later on I uninstalled lol and loaded it back again and everything went fine.

As Alvar suggested, I would remove and reinstall it from playonlinux.